# "Remote Disk" volume always mounted (but only in Finder)

Tags: macos, macbook, osx-lion, macbook-air

I just bought a new Macbook Air the other day. Everything is fine except, for some reason my Finder keeps showing the volume "Remote Disk". Now, I assume this is the shared optical drive that is supported on the air.

The problem is I'm not sharing any drives on any other Macs. In fact, it was there as soon as I booted up for the first time. `Cmd+I` doesn't give me any information about it (it just shows a CD icon) and the drive isn't shown in `/Volumes` or Disk Utility, nor does it respond to being unmounted.

Does anyone know how I can get rid it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On OSX Mavericks 10.9.2 Try dragging the "Remote Disk" symbol wayyy off the finder window. It will disappear with a "poof"

yay

Comment: That gets the job done.

Comment: Más información: In Finder preferences under Sidebar, you can choose what to include on the Sidebar. If you want to hide all connected devices (it lists CDs, DVDs, and iPods) then you simply deselect it.
You probably don't want to do that though. By using the trick in the answer, you'll see in the preferences that the tick is replaced with a dash, which means that it will still show new devices, but will ignore the Remote Disk.
To add it back, deselect and reselect the option.

Comment: Does this prevent mounted disks from appearing in the Finder sidebar in the future?

Answer (score 2):

The "Remote Disc" item in the sidebar is always there for use in connecting to an optical drive on another Mac that's configured for drive sharing, even when you're not actually connected to such a drive. You can remove it from the sidebar in Finder Preferences/Sidebar and turn off "CDs, DVDs, and iPods". I don't know any way to remove it from your top-level display in Finder itself.

Comment: Hiding that also hides any disk images that you load (e.g. when installing from a .dmg file).  It'll *work*, but there are undesirable side effects to it.